# Trouble with [object Object] in ajax response .val .text .html

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hi I am having trouble with ajax returning [object Object] and haven't been able to get it right using similar titled questions. 
I understand a little that it depends on what is format is being returned (although not fully).

Here is my issue: I am searching in the ajax success for various divs in the 2page (php) using .find or.filter (this bit is working ok). I am using the value of those divs to:

1:update divs on the original page
2:use in Jquery IF statements.

It is updating the html divs ok but the IF statements are not working. On investigation I find the IF statement is seeing [object Object]. I think I understand that it is the difference between receiving .html .val and .text but I would like to use .html and the other two as well. Basically I want to update divs with returned text and also trigger IF statements with different returned text/values from page2.

Here is some code, Thanks in advance.

PAGE 1

```
     $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "page2.php",
                data: "VARIABLE1=" + id,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    var data_return=(data);
                    var returned_action_variable = $(data).filter('.action_variable');
                    var returned_text_variable = $(data).filter('.text_variable');


                    if (returned_action_variable == "action_something") {alert("HELLO");
                    $(".div1").html(returned_text_variable);}


                }
            });
```

PAGE2 (simplified return for easier reading, these will actually be php echo's of results from a mysql search)

```
<div class="text_variable">UPDATE TEXT WORKING</div>
<div class="action_variable">action_something</div>
```

Comment: Use JSON.stringify()

Comment: I will try thanks - but ........ how would I use it. Could you possibly show me where to include it in reference to the above example. Even if you just show me the one line. Sorry, just never used it before.

Comment: I may have solved it. Hopefully I not being stupid. It seems to work:                                      var returned_action_variable = $(data).filter('.action_variable').text();

Comment: returned_action_variable is a div, to compare it to "action_something" you need to use returned_action_variable.text, you can't just compare a div to a string.